# Hibernate generates mapping files for the wrong database

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc

I am trying to generate mapping files for DB_NAME, but hibernate generates mapping files for "master" database instead of "DB_NAME". What do I need to do to get hiberate to generate mapping files for "DB_NAME"?

Below is connection property I used in my hibernate.cfg.xml.

I created a TestConnection class to see if I can access DB_NAME. I am able to retrieve data from DB_NAME using the above connection url. I use sql server 2008 and sqljdbc4.jar is in my build path.

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">PASSWORD</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER_NAME\INSTANCE_NAME;DatabaseName=DB_NAME</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">USERNAME</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">DBO</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
```

Comment: exact same effect here, i think it started when i switched to XA-Datasources